# Align a set of numbers with the coefficients in a equation

Tags: equations, align

I want to write an equation in latex like the following one.
[image]

But I can not align a set of numbers with the coefficients completely. Here's my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
LNEP = & -0.23LNEER & +1.21LNCOST & +1.50LNFD & -1.03LNCP & -9.44 \\
& (0.12) & (0.13) & (0.27) & (0.37) & (1.33)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

Could somebody help me pls? Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code snippet an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), with emphasis on _working_. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Change the multiplication symbol to a centered dot.
\let\xtimes\times
\let\times\cdot

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{5}
    \mathrm{LNEP} 
    = -0&.23 \times \mathrm{LNEER} &{}
    + 1&.21 \times \mathrm{LNCOST} &{}
    + 1&.50 \times \mathrm{LNFD} &{}
    - 1&.03 \times \mathrm{LNCP} &{}
    - 9&.44 \\
    (0&.12)&
    (0&.13)&
    (0&.27)&
    (0&.37)&
    (1&.33)
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Please not the changes I made to your code.

- The names (if you have to use multi-letter variables) should be in `\mathrm`.
- I think implicit multiplication looks confusing with those names, better use it explicitly.
- The `{}` between `&` and `+` or `-` ensures the correct spacing around the operators.
- Unlike your example image, I aligned the numbers at the decimal point.

Comment: Rather use `{}+` and `{}-` to have the proper spacing around binary operators.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Your forgot that n alignment points require 2n–1 ampersands. I propose a solution with `alignedat{5}`, and another, simpler, with `stackengine`, which requires no alignment points:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\mystackunder}[2] {\stackMath\stackunder{#1}{\mathclap{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}[t]{5}
LNEP = -0.23&LNEER &{} +1.21 & LNCOST &{} +1.50 & LNFD &{} -1.03 & LNCP &{} -9.44 & \\
 (0.12) & & (0.13) & & (0.27) & & (0.37) & & (1.33)
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\bigskip

\begin{equation}%
LNEP = \mystackunder{-0.23}{(0.12)} LNEER +\mystackunder{1.21}{ (0.13)}LNCOST +\mystackunder{1.50}{(0.27)} LNFD -\mystackunder{1.03}{(0.37)} LNCP -\mystackunder{9.44}{(1.33)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Keep together the coefficient and the accuracy. This allows for making the parentheses having zero width. Between the coefficient and the variable I added a thin space for better clarity.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cfac}[2]{% coefficient with accuracy
  \begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}#1\\\makebox[0pt][r]{$($}#2\makebox[0pt][l]{$)$}\end{array}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\tvar{LNEP} =
\cfac{-0.23}{0.12}\,\tvar{LNEER} + \cfac{1.21}{0.13}\,\tvar{LNCOST} +
\cfac{1.50}{0.27}\,\tvar{LNFD}   - \cfac{1.03}{0.37}\,\tvar{LNCP}   - \cfac{9.44}{1.33}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.